# Using grails rest plugin with proxy authentication?

Tags: grails, google-api

I would like to use the following grails plugin to use Google shorten url API.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/rest

The problem is I need to use it with proxy authentication setting (with username and password)
The API gives me setProxy, but without username and password setting.

How can I set my proxy authentication detail here?

Let me know if there is another alternative. I can't use google-url-shortener plugin because I'm still using grails 1.2.0 which is not compatible with the plugin.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the **Proxy-Authorization** header to authenticate to the proxy.  Something similar to the following:

```
withRest(id: "urlshortener", 
        requestContentType: JSON,
        body: [longUrl: "http://www.google.com/"]
        proxy: [host: "myproxy.acme.com", port: 8080, scheme: "http"]) {
    def response = post(path: '/urlshortener/v1/url') {
        headers.'Proxy-Authorization' = 'Basic ' +
               "${username}:${password}".toString().bytes.encodeBase64()
    }
}
```

Comment: hi John, i think you forgot to add the uri parameter for withRest.. However, after I add, it is still giving me groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: by the way, if I have set the proxy in my Grails installation, why do I still need to set up the proxy connection here... is there any way tell it to use the grails proxy setting? thanks!